# Make a sentence into two lines to make column width narrower.

Tags: tables, columns, multirow

I have a table that has multiwords and columns

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table}[ht]
    %\vspace{-.15cm}
    \caption{Power Consumption measured in mW}
    %\vspace{-.1cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c cc c cc }
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[c]{.1\linewidth}{\centering }} 
      & Labeled & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FBF ($q = 16$)} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FBF ($q = 64$)} \\
    \cmidrule{2-2} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{7-8}
    & size & & {Reduction in size(\%)} & Power & & {Reduction in size(\%)} & Power \\

    \midrule 

            s1 & 125 & & 59.2 & 7.32  & & 26.4 & 0.35 \\
            c2 & 81  & & 72.8 & 0.37 & & 25.9 &  0.36 \\

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:power_consumption}
    \vspace{-.35cm}
    \end{table}  

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

When compiled, I have a table with too wide columns.

I think `Reduction in size(%)` needs some adjustment. How to make that column narrower?

[image]

Comment: `p{1.5cm}` instead of `c` type or use a `\thead{}` from `makecell`. You could use fewer columns (the filler columns are not really necessary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way, using the `makecell` package, a smaller font size, and the `caption` package for a correct vertical spacing between caption and table:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,12pt]{article}%

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell, caption}
\renewcommand\cellalign{bc}
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \footnotesize\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}\vspace{2pt}
  \captionsetup{labelfont = bf}
  \caption{Power Consumption measured in mW}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}ccc@{\,}ccc@{\,}}
    \toprule
    & Labeled & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FBF ($q = 16$)} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FBF ($q = 64$)} \\
    \cmidrule{2-2} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{7-8}
       & Size & & \makecell{Reduction\\ in size(\%)} & Power & &      \makecell{Reduction\\ in size(\%)} & Power \\
    \midrule
    s1 & 125 & & 59.2 & 7.32 & & 26.4 & 0.35 \\
    c2 & 81 & & 72.8 & 0.37 & & 25.9 & 0.36 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \label{table:power_consumption}
\vspace{-2.5ex}
\end{table}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is a proposition. I tried to think out of the box, so it is not exactly faithful to your original design.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[tableposition=above]{caption}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table}[ht]
    %\vspace{-.15cm}
    \caption{Power Consumption in mW}
    %\vspace{-.1cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c
    S[table-format = 3.0]
    *3c
    }
    \toprule
    &        &     & Size      &       \\
    & {Size} &  q  & Reduction & Power \\
    \addlinespace
    & {(-)}  & (-) & (\si{\percent}) & (\si{mW})\\
    \midrule 
    s1 & 125 & 16 & 59.2 & 7.32 \\
       &     & 32 & 26.4 & 0.35 \\
    \addlinespace            
    c2 & 81  & 16 & 72.8 & 0.37 \\
       &     & 32 & 25.9 & 0.36 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:power_consumption}
    \vspace{-.35cm}
    \end{table}  

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Which resulted in:

[image]

**Comments:**

- In any cases, you can split your long column title "Reduction in Size" in two lines like I did in the code by using two lines to define your table header.
- I also used the `siuntix` package to align the numbers in the "size" column.
- I removed the use of `multirow` since it was not really necessary.
- Used the package `caption` with option `tableposition=above` for better placement of the table title.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to changing the font size and the width of a column, which is not always possible, you can also let the table span both columns. This can be invoked with the starred version.

```
\begin{table*}...\end{table*}
```

The placement character `h` is not advisable in this case at all. This also works for figures (and if defined other floating objects).

[image]

```
documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table*}[tb]
  \caption{Power Consumption measured in mW}
  \label{table:power_consumption}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c c cc c cc }
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[c]{.1\linewidth}{\centering }}
      & Labeled & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FBF ($q = 16$)} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FBF ($q = 64$)} \\
    \cmidrule{2-2} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{7-8}
    & size & & {Reduction in size(\%)} & Power & & {Reduction in size(\%)} & Power \\
    \midrule
            s1 & 125 & & 59.2 & 7.32  & & 26.4 & 0.35 \\
            c2 & 81  & & 72.8 & 0.37 & & 25.9 &  0.36 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proposed solution that uses a `tabularx` environment and employs a 10% reduction in the font size (via a `\small` instruction).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\textfloatsep{0.75\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \caption{Power Consumption, in mW}
    \label{table:power_consumption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} l *{5}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
    & Labeled size& 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{FBF ($q = 16$)} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{FBF ($q = 64$)} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6}
    &  & Reduc-tion in size (\%) & Power 
       & Reduc-tion in size (\%) & Power \\
    \midrule 
            s1 & 125 & 59.2 & 7.32 & 26.4 & 0.35 \\
            c2 & 81  & 72.8 & 0.37 & 25.9 & 0.36 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}  

\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \caption{Power Consumption measured in mW}
    \label{table:power_consumption}

    \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{}ccCcCc@{}}
\toprule
    & Labeled 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FBF ($q = 16$)} 
                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FBF ($q = 64$)} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
    & size  &   Reduction\newline
                in size (\%) 
                    & Power &   Reduction\newline
                                in size (\%) 
                                    & Power                     \\    
    \midrule
s1  & 125   & 59.2  & 7.32  & 26.4  & 0.35                      \\
c2  & 81    & 72.8  & 0.37  & 25.9  & 0.36                      \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I use `tabularx` package to accommodate table width to column width, change font to `\footnotesize` that the columns become narrowed. If you like to have wort ''size'' in the midle of the cel, than you need to use `multirow` or similar solution.